# Fringe pattern in Lloyd mirror

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, interference

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_mirror#/media/File:%D0%97%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0.png]
([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_mirror))

What will be the fringe pattern on a Lloyd mirror? More accurately:

Does a Lloyd mirror has same fringe pattern as Young's double slits experiment (YDSE) but just reversed and if they are reversed then will the central fringe remain constructive?

The only thing I know about the Lloyd mirrors is that the sources have a phase difference of π. Unlike Young's double slit experiment, where the sources were at the same phase so the regions of destructive and constructive places should get reversed though I am not sure and my biggest problem is about the central fringe. Will it be constructive or destructive and if so, can you show the math?

Comment: Beside the likely close reason, your questions look *much* better if you ask only a single one. Nobody likes question lists. [Other tips, how to post homework-like questions.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/32426)

Comment: @peterh point noted

Comment: -1 I have no objection to your list of questions, because they are all closely related. IMO it does not make sense to post them as 3 separate questions. However, I have voted to close because you have not shown any effort to answer your own questions, and have not explained what difficulty you are having with them.

Comment: @Jon Custer I think the question should be reopened now as i have now edited as well as shown my efforts

Comment: @sammy gerbil  I think the question should be reopened now as i have now edited as well as shown my efforts

Comment: @JMac I think the question should be reopened now as i have now edited as well as shown my efforts

Comment: @coconut I think the question should be reopened now as i have now edited as well as shown my efforts

Comment: @peterh I think the question should be reopened now as i have now edited as well as shown my efforts

Comment: I don't know the previous edits but this question seems to be okay  as well as  pertaining to  some conceptual facts

Comment: I am sorry, but your writing quality is catastrophal. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) to improve ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main( and only difference) in Lloyd's arrangement comes from the fact that the waves coming from the light source will take up a phase difference of 180 deggres, $\phi= \pi $ and that's because of the reflection to a denser(than air) material( the mirror). So, the result will be a complete exchange between the dark and the light areas of the pattern.

If the distribution of the light intensity is called I, then in it' s experiment we have:

- Young $$I=4I_0 \cos ^2 \frac{\pi dz}{\lambda D}, $$ for zero phase difference in the beginning and same holes and with $D$ the distance between the screen and the wall in front of the source, $d$ the distance between the two holes and $z$ the distance from the centre of the pattern to a spot on the screen.
- Lloyd $$I=4I_0 \sin^2 \frac{\pi d z}{\lambda D} $$

You can see from the intensity relations the reversal of the pattern.
Hope this helps you.

---

[image: YDSE]

The road difference here is the S at the beam coming from the lower hole, that is
$$S=PathDifference=d\sin \theta $$

The logic is similar in Lloyd's mirror:
[image]

You just look for the actual difference between the two beams and you try to find geometrically a relation from the arrangement of the experiment.

Comment: So basically YDSE pattern with the fringes reversed...what about the centeral fringe?will it be dark or bright and what is it's path difference?

Comment: @harambe Updated. I believe you can take it from here. Ciao.